# SetRange for an input field using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

We have an input field for entering hour.
So only values between 0 and 12 should be entered.

```
<input type="text" id="hour-field">
```

Which is the best way to achieve this using AngularJs. Should I use directives or ng-keyup for this.Which is more efficient.

Please note all the other keyevents other than 0-9 has to be disabled.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.number

Answer (score 0):

Check [Angular Ui-Utils](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/)

Check the ui.mask directive

Comment: Can I have a custom one.I don't want to include a library for such a functionality.